# Troubles making a custom Navbar

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to make a website. I'm new in front-end, so sometimes have troubles like that.

The aim is to make a custom navbar, which is a right trapezoid. I've tried to make it through `<svg>` and `<polygon>`, putting some content inside with `<foreignObject>`, but positioning in it is awful and `<svg>` can't resize in height through percentage.

Is there a way to make something similar to the bar in the photo, or can you help me with svg? Really need your help. Thanks in advance.

There's the photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzDSi.png

Comment: You can totally make that with pure css, no need for svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trapezoid can be made by a block element with zero height (height of 0px), a width greater than zero and a border, that is transparent except for one side.

HTML:

```
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.trapezoid {
    width: 50px;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black;
}
```

and with a little positioning, you can put some text over it:

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 200px solid #346;
}
.items {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="items">Item One<br>Item Two<br>Item Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to remove the link to docs, and copy any relevant info over? Since you're the only contributor to that example, you won't need to worry about attribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Background Shape Customizer](http://enjoycss.com/Ckp#box)

```
.parallelogram {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: -149px;
  padding: 15% 24% 43% 14%;
  border: none;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #00354D;
  -webkit-transform:    skewX(-20deg);
  transform:    skewX(-20deg);
}
```